# Regex to match if it contains same character 0 or 2 or 4 times next to each other

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching, match

I need to create regex rule to match this kind of strings (the looking letter is 'a'):

- aa
- aaaa
- aabb
- aaaagg
- cccaazz
- dddaaaazz

but not:

- aaa
- aaaaa
- abb
- bbbaaa
- bbaazza

Tried with `[a]{2}|[a]{4}` but this wasn't working. Any idea?

Comment: What about `aabba`? `aabbaa`? `abbaa`? `aaaaaa`?

Comment: Nope, `a` can be 0 or 2 or 4 times next to each other only. It can't be divided by any other thing.

Comment: why this `cccaazz`(three `c` characters) is valid and `abb` is not in your examples?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest odd a

Comment: `/^(?:[^a]*(?:a{2})?(?:a{4})?[^a]*)+$/`

Comment: `a` must be 0 or 2 or 4 times in whole string. 1 or 3 times is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[^a]*(?:aa){0,2}[^a]*$/
```

1. We need `^` and `$` to match the whole string.
2. The `[^a]*` match any number of non-`a`s. This makes sure only the middle part contains `a`s.
3. `(?:aa){0,2}` matches zero aas (= empty), one aa (= `aa`) or two aas (= `aaaa`).

---

```
>>> ['aa', 'aaaa', 'aabb', 'aaaagg', 'cccaazz', 'dddaaaazz', 'aaa', 'aaaaa', 'abb', 'bbbaaa', 'bbaazza']
    .map(c => `${c}: ${/^[^a]*(?:aa){0,2}[^a]*$/.test(c)}`).join('\n')
"aa: true
aaaa: true
aabb: true
aaaagg: true
cccaazz: true
dddaaaazz: true
aaa: false
aaaaa: false
abb: false
bbbaaa: false
bbaazza: false"
```

Comment: Almost, still not working. The string can be only `a` or `aabb` or `ccaaaa`

Comment: @Nosenation Isn't `a` a non-matching case? It contains only one `a`. `aabb` and `ccaaaa` works for this regex.

Comment: Yes I mean that it could start with `aa` or end with `aa`. Tried your regex but no match. It matches too much.

Link: https://regex101.com/r/4dQbJz/1

Comment: @Nosenation That's because `[^a]` matches new lines too. Use `[^a\n]` in regex101. Note that `/m` flag does not mean it will match line-by-line, the whole piece of text is still searched together.

Comment: Ok. Btw: what can I do to have `a` min 0 times, without upper limit but can't be divided by any other character? For example:

- vvaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzz is ok
- vvaaaaazaaaazzzzz isn't ok

Comment: @Nosenation Change the `{0,2}` to other quantifiers.